# Chisel language how to best use Queues?

Tags: chisel

I'm new in chisel, if someone can explain the role of:

1- Queue
2- DecoupledIO
3- Decoupled
3- ValidIO
4- Valid

Is this piece of chisel code correct?

---

...

```
val a = Decoupled()
val b = Decoupled()
val c = Decoupled()
```

...

```
val Reg_a = Reg(UInt())
val Reg_b = Reg(UInt())
```

...

```
when(io.a.valid && io.a.ready && io.b.valid && io.b.ready && io.c.valid &&     io.c.ready)
{

  Reg_a := io.a.bits.data
  Reg_b := io.b.bits.data
}

io.c.bits := Reg_a & Reg_b
```

...

```
Module.io.a    <>    Queue(Module_1.io.a_1)
Module.io.b    <>    Queue(Module_1.io.b_1)
Module_1.io.c_1 <>   Queue(Module.io.c)
```

regards!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. **Queue** is a hardware module that implements a first in, first out queue with DecoupledIO inputs and outputs
2. **DecoupledIO** is a ready/valid interface type with members ready, valid, and bits
3. **Decoupled** is a helper to construct DecoupledIO from some other type
4. **ValidIO** is similar to DecoupledIO except that it only has valid and bits
5. **Valid** is similar to Decoupled for constructing ValidIOs

I can't tell what the code is trying to do, but here's an example of a Module that has 2 DecoupledIO inputs and 1 DecoupledIO output. It buffers the inputs with queues and then connects the output to the sum of the inputs:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._

class QueueModule extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(32.W))) // valid and bits are inputs
    val b = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(32.W)))
    val z = Decoupled(UInt(32.W)) // valid and bits are outputs
  })
  // Note that a, b, and z are all of type DecoupledIO

  // Buffer the inputs with queues
  val qa = Queue(io.a) // io.a is the input to the FIFO
                       // qa is DecoupledIO output from FIFO
  val qb = Queue(io.b)

  // We only dequeue when io.z is ready
  qa.nodeq() // equivalent to qa.ready := false.B
  qb.nodeq()

  // When qa and qb have valid inputs and io.z is ready for an output
  when (qa.valid && qb.valid && io.z.ready) {
    io.z.enq(qa.deq() + qb.deq())
    /* The above is short for
      io.z.valid := true.B
      io.z.bits := qa.bits + qb.bits
      qa.ready := true.B
      qb.ready := true.B
    */
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!